# Inconsistency in the namespace of controller mapped to Rails' route concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-routing

```
  concern :votable do
    resources :votes, only: [:index, :create]
  end

  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1 do
      namespace :problems do
        resources :details, only: [:index, :show], concerns: :votable
```

My routes.rb is as above and I put VotesController in `api\v1\votes_controller.rb`. The class name is  `Api::V1::VotesController`

It run ok on my local machine (`Windows 7, ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [i386-mingw32], Rails 4.1.5`), however it works differently on Heroku (`ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-linux], Rails 4.1.5`). From the logs, it seems to expect the VotesController to be inside `api\v1\problems\votes_controller.rb`

Error log:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::V1::Problems::VotesController):
```

Is it known bug? If I want to make the votes_controller.rb not to be inside Api::V1::Problems namespace, how should I configure it?

I want it to be generic & reusable by any other controllers, so I avoid putting it under api:v1:problems directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your routes to have `scope` instead of `namespace`:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1 do
      scope '/problems' do
        resources :details, only: [:index, :show], concerns: :votable
```

This should generate route like this:

```
/api/v1/problems/votes => Api::V1::VotesController
```

**UPDATE:**

```
concern :votable do
  resources :votes, only: [:index, :create]
end

namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
  namespace :v1 do
    scope 'problems' do
      resources :details, only: [:index, :show], concerns: :votable, controller: '/problems/details'
    end
  end
end
```

routes:

```
$ rake routes|grep 'api'
api_v1_detail_votes GET    /api/v1/problems/details/:detail_id/votes(.:format) api/v1/votes#index {:format=>:json}
                    POST   /api/v1/problems/details/:detail_id/votes(.:format) api/v1/votes#create {:format=>:json}
     api_v1_details GET    /api/v1/problems/details(.:format)                  api/v1//problems/details#index {:format=>:json}
      api_v1_detail GET    /api/v1/problems/details/:id(.:format)              api/v1//problems/details#show {:format=>:json}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: But I also want the details class to be under api/v1/problems folder as it is specific to api/v1/problems :D

Comment: like: `/api/v1/problems/details => Api::V1::Problems::Details`?